# Ubuntu 13 doesn't have an option for screen resolution 1600x900 for NVidia graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution, screen

I am looking for a way to configure my display to the correct resolution of 1600x900. When I initially installed Ubuntu 13 the display resolution was perfect but after a few updates it now only gives me a couple of low resolution options.

It is an Acer computer with an Nvidia graphics card and I am using the Nvidia 309 driver.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) and enter `xrandr -q`

The output should look something like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   39.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

where in this case, **LVDS1** is the output which your monitor is connected to.

Now enter `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900` (replace LVDS1 with the correct output if necessary). The output should now have the correct resolution.

To make the changes permanent, you need to put the above command into your .xprofile file.
To do this, type `nano ~/.xprofile` in a terminal. Enter the line `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900` and save (`Ctrl`+`O`, `Enter`, `Ctrl`+`X`).